# Как увеличить отступы между строками таблицы или как-то лучше можно?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, табличная-верстка

Подскажите пжста, как увеличить отступы между строками таблицы до уровня, примерно, равного высоте этих цифр-изображений? И еще, ячейку с "02" не смог поставить ровно, 01 и 03 вроде смотрибельны.

```html
<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; height: 74px;">
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 54px;">
<td style="width: 55%; height: 54px; text-align: right;" colspan="2"><img loading="lazy" src="https://suik.online/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/grey-01.png" width="75" height="75" alt="" class="wp-image-299 alignnone size-thumbnail"></td>
<td style="width: 45%; height: 54px;">Развертывание и работы системы происходит на любом оборудовании, по техническому задании заказчика, включая внутренние серверы</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 10px;">
<td style="width: 43.5%; height: 10px; text-align: right;">Многоступенчатая система аутентификации для работы с системой, в том числе через отпечатки пальцев, ретроспективный контроль за доступом к информации</td>
<td style="width: 56.5%; height: 10px; text-align: left;" colspan="2"><img loading="lazy" src="https://suik.online/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/grey-02.png" width="75" height="75" alt="" class="wp-image-300 alignnone size-full"></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 0px;">
<td style="width: 55%; height: 10px; text-align: right;" colspan="2"><img loading="lazy" src="https://suik.online/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/grey-03.png" width="75" height="75" alt="" class="wp-image-301 alignnone size-thumbnail"></td>
<td style="width: 45%; height: 10px;">Использование системы только силами внутренних сотрудников без привлечения третьих лиц</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Как итог хочется чтобы выглядело примерно как на данном изображении
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ширина этого дела д.б. около 90% от ширина экрана, но не критично. Иной способ также интересен.

С уважением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Иной способ также интересен.

табличной верстке место в музее.

```css
#my_table{
display: grid;
height: 200px;
width: 500px;
grid-template:
".. h1 pa" 1fr
"pb h1 .." 1fr
".. h1 pc" 1fr / 4fr 1fr 4fr;
grid-gap: 5px; /* отступы */}

h1{
grid-column: 2;
text-align: center;
color: gray;
font-size: 70px;}

h1, p{
border: 1px solid red;
align-self: center;
justify-self: center;
margin: 0;
padding: 5px;}
#a{grid-area: pa;}
#b{grid-area: pb;}
#c{grid-area: pc;}
```

```html
<div id='my_table'>
<h1>01</h1>
<h1>02</h1>
<h1>03</h1>
<p id='a'>Развертывание и работы системы происходит на любом оборудовании, по техническому задании заказчика, включая внутренние серверы</p>
<p id='b'>Многоступенчатая система аутентификации для работы с системой, в том числе через отпечатки пальцев, ретроспективный контроль за доступом к информации</p>
<p id='c'>Использование системы только силами внутренних сотрудников без привлечения третьих лиц</p>
</div>
```